# Developing Mozilla Firefox for Linux on Windows

Tags: firefox, c++, development, compatibility, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to make some contribution to Mozilla Firefox (with the little C++ I know). Can I build, run and debug Firefox for Linux using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) ? If yes, should I install anything specific for this (for example: Window systems) ?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance! Favour returned question upvoted! (dunno why it attracted a downvote except maybe that the solution is off-topic here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do that [officially](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq).

Yes, there is a way of doing that using [XMing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xming) but that's a pure Windows solution which is off topic here on Unix&Linux but on-topic on our sister site https://superuser.com.